# How to skip a cell / return no cell from GetCell method, UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

I've got a List of 'TagInstances' each containing a 'color' string value.

```
List<TagInstance> tags
```

In my UICollectionView I would like to forgo initialization of tagCells if :

```
tags[index.Path].color = "undefined"
```

Im trying to do this in the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" / "GetCell" method :

```
[Export("collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:")]
public UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = (TagCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("tagCell", indexPath);

    var thisTag = tags[indexPath.Row];

    if (thisTag.color == "undefined") { /* todo: Skip over this cell somehow */ }

    try
    {
        var color = UIColor.Clear.FromHex(thisTag.color);

        cell.SetUIWithData(color, thisTag.abbreviation);

        cell.AddBorderAndShadow();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"\ncolor : { thisTag.color }\nThrows an exception : \n{ ex }\n");
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Currently my collection view appears with a gap where any TagInstance had and undefined color. I would like for the collection to appear without that gap. Is this possible?

Comment: The proper solution is to not include those values in your collection view data source.

Comment: Assign a filtered dataset that excludes the `undefined` elements..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As rmaddy and SushiHangover said, proper way to do that is have correct datasource which only has items you want to display.

In some way, alternative would be just sizing those unwanted cells to width/height = 0. To do so with UICollectionView, you have to derive from UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override `LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect` method to then return `Size = CGSize.Empty` for those elements you don't want to see.

Please see section *Subclassing UICollectionViewFlowLayout* in [Xamarin Docs in Introduction to UICollectionView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_collection_views/#Subclassing_UICollectionViewFlowLayout).

Again, correct and easier way to do that is to filter elements at your data source level, as SushiHangover and rmaddy suggest.

Answer (score 2):

1) Remove that data from datasource for which you dont want to display cell in collectionview.

```
tags.RemoveAll(p => p.color== "undefined" );
```

**or**

2) If you want to keep that data in list for other reason, use GetSizeForItem  method of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  .

use following in UICollectionviewSource

```
[Export ("collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:"), CompilerGenerated]
public virtual CGSize GetSizeForItem (UICollectionView collectionView, UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
var thisTag = tags[indexPath.Row];

if (thisTag.color == "undefined")
        return new CGSize(0,0);
else 
    return new CGSize (yoruwidth, yourheigh);
}
```